# how to make symbology by multiple attribute values

Tags: symbols, qgis

By default we classifier layers by values of a field, now i want to make a symbology to each polygone by values of rows like the picture. i mean classify by name of cities

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Akv.png)

How to give to each polygone(city) colors of (DETAILS) when is (STATUS) is YES
maybe i will have many colors in the same polygone when (STATUS) is Yes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question right, but you can make a categorized classification and use an expression instead of a field name. For example:

`"CITY" || ' ' || "DETAILS"`

This will take the value from the "CITY" column, add a space and add the value from the "DETAILS" column. When you click "Classify", QGIS will create an ordered list of every unique combination. Then you can manually change the symbols, or delete the entries you don't need.

Comment: thank you for your answer that's near of what i want but exactly i am intresting to display many colors(DETAILS) when (STATUS) is YES ; like the Example of PARIS should show 2 colors of A and B in the some polygone PARIS and the Samething for the otherscities